# go/types.Identical cannot compare two same types in other package?

Tags: go

I write some code to get special type by "go/types"

```
import (
    "go/ast"
    "go/importer"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
    "go/types"
    "log"
)    

const (
    Src = `
package types

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

var (
    IOReader    io.Reader
    Err         error
    StatusCode  int
    Request     *http.Request
    Response    *http.Response
)
`
)

const (
    TypeIOReader   = "IOReader"
    TypeErr        = "Err"
    TypeStatusCode = "StatusCode"
    TypeRequest    = "Request"
    TypeResponse   = "Response"
)


func GetType(name string) types.Type {
    fset := token.NewFileSet()
    file, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "types.go", Src, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    conf := types.Config{Importer: importer.Default()}
    pkg, err := conf.Check("impler/types", fset, []*ast.File{file}, nil)
    return pkg.Scope().Lookup(name).Type()
}
```

The function `GetType(name string) types.Type` can make it.

And when I compare two types, I get some strange results

```
log.Println(types.Identical(GetType(TypeResponse), GetType(TypeResponse)))
log.Println(types.Identical(GetType(TypeIOReader), GetType(TypeIOReader)))
log.Println(types.Identical(GetType(TypeStatusCode), GetType(TypeStatusCode)))
log.Println(types.Identical(GetType(TypeErr), GetType(TypeErr)))
```

The result is

```
false
false
true
true
```

It seems `types.Identical` cannot compare two same types in other package?
How can I compare them?

Is `types.TypeString(typ1, nil) == types.TypeString(typ2, nil)` robust enough?

Comment: Did you check the error returned from conf.Check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're re-parsing the source every time, creating a new instance of `types.Package` and its associated `types.Scope` which results in the *named* types originating from different declarations ([link](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/50bd1c4d4eb4fac8ddeb5f063c099daccfb71b26/src/go/types/predicates.go#L282-L284)).

Builtin types like `int` and `error` for which you got `true` are basic types that are treated differently by the comparison ([link](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/cd016af6b6bbbeeb1c14fea574914862a50c3ad6/src/go/types/predicates.go#L136-L147)). They are also declared in the "universe" scope which, I believe, is always the same no matter how many times you re-parse the `Src` ([link](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/cd016af6b6bbbeeb1c14fea574914862a50c3ad6/src/go/types/universe.go#L15-L17)).

To fix your problem you have to parse the source once, and then share the resulting `*types.Package`.

```
package main

import (
    "go/ast"
    "go/importer"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
    "go/types"
    "log"
)

const Src = `
package types

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

var (
    IOReader    io.Reader
    Response    *http.Response
)
`


const (
    TypeIOReader = "IOReader"
    TypeResponse = "Response"
)

func GetType(name string, pkg *types.Package) types.Type {
    return pkg.Scope().Lookup(name).Type()
}

func main() {
    fset := token.NewFileSet()
    file, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "types.go", Src, 0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    conf := types.Config{Importer: importer.Default()}
    pkg, err := conf.Check("impler/types", fset, []*ast.File{file}, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    log.Println(types.Identical(GetType(TypeResponse, pkg), GetType(TypeResponse, pkg)))
    log.Println(types.Identical(GetType(TypeIOReader, pkg), GetType(TypeIOReader, pkg)))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Types in Go with different names are treated as different, even they have the same structure. Here's more information about golang type rules: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity

If you wish to compare them you may to convert one value to another type:

```
     type A {...} // some declaration

     type B {...} // the same declaration 

     if a == A(b) {...}
```

Comment: OP is using [`types.Identical`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/#Identical) to compare two instances of [`types.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/#Type). The comparison that fails for OP is of an *imported* type, same name, same package, but imported as opposed to package-local. Has nothing to do with A != B. Has to do with p.A != p.A.